# Why are partial derivatives of Energy and Co-Energy with respect to x opposite numbers?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, power, inductance

In a system where the flux linkage $\lambda = \lambda(x, i)$ is a function of dispalcement $x$ and current $i$.

Its energy is defined as

$$
W = \int_{0}^{\lambda} i(\lambda', x)d\lambda'.
$$

Its co-energy is

$$
W' = \int_{0}^{i} \lambda(i', x)di'.
$$

And

$$
W = \color{Red}{ \lambda i} - W'.
$$

The textbook then explained that the Force of electric origin

$$
f^e = +\frac{\partial }{\partial x} W' = -\frac{\partial }{\partial x} W.
$$

My question is that why are $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} W'$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial x} W$ opposite numbers? i.e. Why the partial derivative of $\color{Red}{ \lambda i}$ with respect to $x$ is $0$, given that $\lambda$ is a function of $i$ and $x$?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!